# Global variables in apache cocoon piplines

Tags: apache-cocoon

I have some static variables used the XSL which are currently stored in sitemap.xml as global variables.

```
<map:pipelines>
   <map:component-configurations>
      <global-variables>
          ...
      </global-variables>
   </map:component-configurations>
...
```

This is all well and good but, some of the variables are deployment specific so need to be changed when the web app starts up. Basically, I need a small number of properties, stored externally to the .WAR to be available in the XSLT.

Has anyone needed to do something similar? If so what approach did you use?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For reference, it's worth checking out the cocoon input module [RequestModule](http://wiki.apache.org/cocoon/InputModules#RequestModule__.28JXPath.29%20RequestModule)

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly do these properties need to be stored outside of the WAR?  Cocoon already keeps plenty of deployment-specific configuration inside `WEB-INF`.

If you're simply trying to keep the configuration out of the *sitemap*, `.properties` files may be your solution.  The properties defined in `**.properties` in `WEB-INF` are available for use in Cocoon's sitemaps using `${property-name}` notation.

Note that my answer is based off my experience with Cocoon 2.1.11; it may work differently in other versions.